# Hibernate & Spring 3 not saving

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, transactions

I am using hibernate 3 and spring 3.0.7, I am trying to get my code to save an entity to the database but it just won't do it.

I have tried everything with it but it seems like there is something I am doing wrong.

here is my class that uses the dao method

> public boolean saveData(DataHolder holder,int type,Owners found){

```
    TempData temp = new TempData();
    temp.setDate(holder.getDate());
    temp.setTimestamp(new Timestamp(holder.getDate().getTime()));
    temp.setName(holder.getName());
    temp.setComId(holder.getCom().getComId());
    temp.setSymbol(holder.getCom().getSymbol());
    temp.setPercent(holder.getPercent());
    if(type == 1){
        temp.setOwnerId(found.getOwnerId());
        temp.setOwnerType(found.getType());
        tempDao.addTemp(temp);
        return true;
    }
    else{
        tempDao.addTemp(temp);
        return false;
    }
}
```

ofcourse it's a bean annotated with component

and here is my dao's add method thats not working

> public boolean addTemp(TempData entity){
>          try {
>               getSession().save(entity);
>               return true;
>           } catch (Exception e) {
>               e.printStackTrace();
>               return false;
>           }
>       }

and this is my entity

> @Component
>   public class TempData {

```
private int tempId;
private Date date;
private Timestamp timestamp;
private String name;
private String ownerType;
private Integer ownerId;
private String symbol;
private Integer comId;
private Double percent;

public int getTempId() {
    return tempId;
}

public void setTempId(int tempId) {
    this.tempId = tempId;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getOwnerType() {
    return ownerType;
}

public void setOwnerType(String ownerType) {
    this.ownerType = ownerType;
}

public Integer getOwnerId() {
    return ownerId;
}

public void setOwnerId(Integer ownerId) {
    this.ownerId = ownerId;
}

public String getSymbol() {
    return symbol;
}

public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
}

public Integer getComId() {
    return comId;
}

public void setComId(Integer comId) {
    this.comId = comId;
}

public Double getPercent() {
    return percent;
}

public void setPercent(Double percent) {
    this.percent = percent;
}
```

and this is my hbm

> 

and this is spring config's part thats related

> 

```
<tx:advice id="tx" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="find*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW"/>
        <tx:method name="add*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="tx" pointcut="execution(* *..AbstractDao.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="tx" pointcut="execution(* *..TempDataDao.addTemp(..))" />
</aop:config>
```

thing is it retrieves data perfectly but when it comes to saving data it just don't work, and the same methods in just different projects work perfectly, but here they just don't and the log says nothing about any error or something, i even tried to change the name of the table mapped to a false one but still no errors and completes the transaction,

what am i missing here ?

**EDIT**

This is what my debugger shows, and just that

```
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (HibernateTransactionManager.java:569) - Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/parse_web, UserName=root@localhost, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver]
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (SessionImpl.java:265) - opened session at timestamp: 13683691714
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (AbstractSaveEventListener.java:134) - generated identifier: 0, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.Assigned
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:752) - Initiating transaction commit
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (HibernateTransactionManager.java:652) - Committing Hibernate transaction on Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@573a46b6]
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (JDBCTransaction.java:130) - commit
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (JDBCTransaction.java:223) - re-enabling autocommit
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (JDBCTransaction.java:143) - committed JDBC Connection
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (ConnectionManager.java:325) - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (HibernateTransactionManager.java:734) - Closing Hibernate Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@573a46b6] after transaction
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (SessionFactoryUtils.java:789) - Closing Hibernate Session
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (ConnectionManager.java:464) - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-7] (ConnectionManager.java:325) - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
```

this is how i get my session

```
public Session getSession(){
        return (this.factory.getCurrentSession()==null)?
                this.factory.getCurrentSession() : this.factory.openSession();
    }
```

Comment: Did you add @Transactional in your Service layer or DAO layer?

Comment: i am using xml based transaction managment, and as i said it does manage it because the log says that transaction begun and committed and everything is good but just the saving is wrong

Comment: I would start by removing the try/catch block from the DAO method. If there is an exception, let it propagate to rollback the transaction, and to be notified of the error. Don't catch exceptions that you can't handle properly.

Comment: i added it to try to find something maybe i was missig it

Comment: How do you determine that it doesn't work? Have you turned hibernate SQL logging on?

Comment: how do I turn it own ? I determine by going to the DB and checking the table to find that it's still empty

Comment: I've turned it on and still only this information of the debugger is given, the selection statements are shown fully, but there is no insert ones

Comment: Show us how the code of getSession(). Show us how you get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely caused by the way you get a session. The session you get is in no way linked to the Spring transaction manager, and what you're doing with it is done outside of the Spring transaction. You should define a Spring-based session factory in your spring context, and inject it in your DAO, as explained in [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-session-factory-setup).

Comment: Thanks that explains alot, sot the problem was nothing to do with hibernate and I spent 2 days looking in the wrong bug, it also explains why it can retrieve values but not set them.